# stereo with two webcams

Tags: stereo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all, i have two webcams and want run these at same time. i use usb_cam package and mylaunch is this:

```
<launch>
 <group ns="camera1">
  <node name="usb_cam1" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video1" />
    <param name="image_width" value="640" />
    <param name="image_height" value="480" />
    <param name="pixel_format" value="mjpeg" />
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="yuyv" />
    <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>
  </node>
  <node name="image_view" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <remap from="image" to="/camera1/usb_cam1/image_raw"/>
    <param name="autosize" value="true" />
  </node>
 </group>

<group ns="camera2">
  <node name="usb_cam2" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video2" />
    <param name="image_width" value="640" />
    <param name="image_height" value="480" />
    <param name="pixel_format" value="mjpeg" />
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="yuyv" />
    <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>
  </node>
  <node name="image_view" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <remap from="image" to="/camera2/usb_cam2/image_raw"/>
    <param name="autosize" value="true" />
  </node>
 </group>
</launch>
```

but when roslaunch my launch file, one webcam run and others is off and instead that the webcam from laptop is on!
what is problem?!
please help me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274146/stereo-with-two-webcams/) by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-10-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FrozenCh](https://answers.ros.org/users/29243/frozench/) on 2017-10-26**:
check your video_device. I guess that there are three devices and one of them belongs to your laptop cam.

**Comment by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on 2017-10-26**:
how can i check video_device.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Linux, video devices are per default named `/dev/videoX` with X counting up. The order might change depending on multiple factors (for instance when the device was plugged in, already at boot or afterwards). The right way to work around this is using udev rules. To quote the [Debian Wiki on udev](https://wiki.debian.org/udev):

> udev allows for rules that specify
> what name is given to a device,
> regardless of which port it is plugged
> into. For example, a rule to always
> mount a hard drive with manufacturer
> "iRiver" and device code "ABC" as
> /dev/iriver is possible. This
> consistent naming of devices
> guarantees that scripts dependent on a
> specific device's existence will not
> be broken.

If you search for "udev webcam" you should find lots of information about how to setup udev rules for your webcams. Your rules should look somewhat similar to this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", BUS=="usb", ATTRS{vendor}=="0x046d", ATTRS{device}=="0x0807", NAME="webcam_left"
SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", BUS=="usb", ATTRS{vendor}=="0x046d", ATTRS{device}=="0x0808", NAME="webcam_right"
```

You would then use `/dev/webcam_left` and `/dev/webcam_right` in your launch file.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on 2017-10-26**:
i am new in ros , and i don't know how can i use udev?!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-26**:
`udev` is a Linux (OS) subsystem, it is not something provided by ROS.

**Comment by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on 2017-10-26**:
how can i use udev for webcams?

**Comment by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on 2017-10-26**:
i am new in linux and i don't know how can i use udev?!
please help me

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-26**:
First: please don't badger us. We're all volunteers here and are helping you for free.

Second: `udev` is not part of ROS, so please use a more appropriate (ie: Linux oriented) support forum for that. @Stefan Kohlbrecher has already linked you to relevant docs on the Debian wiki. If things are ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-26**:
.. still unclear, ask a question on `askubuntu` or one of the Ubuntu forums (provided you are using Ubuntu).

**Comment by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on 2017-10-27**:
thanks stefan